# Enrique Santos L's "Proof that no odd perfect number exists"

Tags: proof-explanation, solution-verification, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

**Background**

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.  A number $l$ is called *perfect* if $\sigma(l)=2l$.

Let $n$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) given in the so-called *Eulerian form* $n = p^k m^2$ where $p$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

**Motivation**

Has anybody seen

> Enrique Santos L's "[Proof that no odd perfect number exists](http://unsolvedproblems.org/S111.pdf)"?

From Eq. (6) in that paper, we have
$$p^x a = \sigma(a) \frac{\sigma(p^x)}{2},$$
where it is implied that $a = m^2$ and $x = k$ (to use our notation).

Then in the section **Separation in two equations** in that paper, Enrique claims that $\sigma(a)$ has to be coprime to $a$, which I know to be false since
$$\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))=\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k}=\frac{m^2}{\sigma(p^k)/2} \geq 3,$$
a result of [Dris from 2012](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html).

**Inquiry**

> Can the rest of the "proof argument" be salvaged?  Is it possible to mend Enrique's "proof argument" to hopefully produce some partial results on odd perfect numbers?

Comment: Enrique Santos has two new preprints on this subject: **(1)** [Every perfect number has only one odd prime factor (July 2020)](http://unsolvedproblems.org/S140.pdf); and **(2)** [Proof that no odd perfect number exists (July 2018, Resubmitted October 2021)](http://unsolvedproblems.org/S153.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Eulerian form is not used in the paper "[Proof that no odd perfect number exists](http://unsolvedproblems.org/S111.pdf)", as it is not used the assumption that $n$ has to be odd. Then it is not correct the claim that "it is implied that $a = m^2$", which would be valid only under the odd $n$ assumption. That is why your result cannot be applied also. In fact, $σ(a)$ is co-prime to $a$ in every known perfect number.

The cited paper has an important flaw, anyway, that is the affirmation that "it should be obvious" that the following relation

$$
 \begin{align} 
\ p^x = \prod_i {σ(q_i^{s_i + r_i}) \over q_i^{r_i}} 
= {\prod_i ( 1 + q_i + ... + q_i^{s_i + r_i} ) \over \prod_i q_i^{r_i}} 
\end{align} 
$$

can not be integer "unless the denominator is 1". It is not obvious at all, and it has not been proved later also.

Comment: Thank you for your response, @enrique.  Just so we are on the same page:  You are saying that in the equation
$$p^x a = \sigma(a) \frac{\sigma(p^x)}{2}$$
$a$ is not $m^2$, therefore $x$ is not odd, hence $x$ is even, and consequently
$$\frac{\sigma(p^x)}{2}$$
is not an integer?

Comment: I think $\gcd(a, \sigma(a)) = 1$ only works when $a = 2^{q-1}$, where $2^{q-1} (2^q - 1)$ is an *even perfect number*.  So logically, you are *correct* in claiming that $\gcd(a, \sigma(a)) = 1$ in every *known* perfect number (as no odd perfect number has been discovered).  Nonetheless, because of the Eulerian form, and the fact that the special/Euler prime is the lone prime that has an odd exponent in the prime factorization of an odd perfect number, then my stated result implies that 
$$\gcd(a, \sigma(a)) = \gcd(m^2, \sigma(m^2)) \geq 3.$$
Hence, my contention that... (continued)

Comment: $a$ is *not* coprime to $\sigma(a)$ for odd perfect numbers, and thus my rebuttal to your claim that $\gcd(a,\sigma(a))=1$ holds in all cases.

Comment: Note that your definition of $p$ and $x$ is such that
$$\frac{\sigma(p^x)}{2}$$
must be an integer.  In which case, $x$ must be odd.  If we are considering the case of odd perfect numbers, $p$ must then be the special/Euler prime.  I hope that you now see my point, @enrique.

Comment: I wrote in my paper: _"We choose the coprime factor $p^x$ such that $σ(p^x)$ is even."_ So $x$ must be odd, independently of $a$ being a square or not.

Comment: Eulerian form is not valid for all perfect numbers, that is why I didn't use it on my article. Anyway, you are right that I didn't get to prove that $gcd( a, σ(a) ) = 1$, as I didn't prove formula (8), the one on this answer. 

You say: "I think $gcd( a, σ(a) ) = 1$ only works when $a = 2^{q - 1}$, where $2^{q - 1} (2^q - 1)$ is an _even perfect number_." Well, in fact **that is what I do prove** in the rest of my article.

Comment: So now consider the case of *odd perfect numbers*, for which we have the Eulerian form, @enrique.  You chose the coprime factor $p^x$ such that $\sigma(p^x)$ is even.  So yes, $x$ must be odd.  But (and this is my **main point**) note that:  The special/Euler prime is the lone prime of an *odd perfect number* that must have an odd exponent.  That means that your chosen $p$ is the special/Euler prime (in the case of *odd perfect numbers*), with exponent $k$ (to use my notation).  And then $a=m^2$, and therefore my claim that
$$\gcd(a,\sigma(a))=\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2)) \geq 3.$$

Comment: The fact that $\gcd(a,\sigma(a))=1$ for $a = 2^{q-1}$ is surely trivial, is it not?  Note here that when $q$ is an odd prime, then $q - 1$ is even, so that $2^{q-1}$ is a square.  (Of course, you will have to exclude the *squarefree even perfect number* $6$.)

Comment: I invite you to read more about this (the Eulerian form of *odd* perfect numbers and the Euclidean form of *even* perfect numbers) in [Euclid-Euler Heuristics for Perfect Numbers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.5616v4.pdf).

Comment: The $2$ in the definition $σ(N) = 2·N$  makes mandatory that at least one prime power of $N$ has an even sum of divisors, $σ(p^x) = 1 + p + ... + p^x$. Then, $p$ and $x$ must both be odd always, so my chosen $p$ is the _special prime_ in any case of perfect number, odd or even. It is never "implied that $a = m^2$" in my article, as I deal every time with the general case.

Comment: The implication $gcd( a, σ(a) ) = 1 \Longrightarrow a = 2^{q-1}$ is what I prove on my article. The lack of a correct proof of the premise ($σ(a)$ coprime to $a$) is the flaw of my article.

Comment: I think I see your point now, @enrique.  However, I do believe that you will never be able to prove that $\gcd(a, \sigma(a)) = 1$ unconditionally, since as I have already explained at length above, $\gcd(a, \sigma(a)) \geq 3$ for *odd* perfect numbers.